# javascript pass value from select multiple to a selected textfield

Tags: javascript, html

i have multiple textfield and a select multiple
like this

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="2"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="3"><br>
<input type="text" placeholder="4"><br>

<select multiple="multiple">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

lets just say i clicked on textfield 1 and then i clicked on select multiple "One"

and the value "One" will passed to textfield 1 because i clicked the textfield 1 before..

and if instead i clicked the textfield 2 then the "One" will passed to textfield 2

Comment: Did you make any javascript yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can see some jQuery answes here, though asked for JS.
Here is the JS one:

```
var activeInput = false;
window.onload = function(event) { 
  allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (i = 0; i < allInputs.length; i++)
  {
    allInputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){activeInput = this;});
  }

  allOptions = document.getElementsByTagName('option');

  for (i = 0; i < allOptions.length; i++)
  {
    allOptions[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ if (activeInput){activeInput.value = this.text;}});
  }
}();
```

Comment: Nice, I love Javascript. Yet it's too much stuff to write for a lazy guy like me.

Comment: thanks for the answer sir, altough i will using the jQuery one by @DaanHeskes but i will mark this as the answer because what i was asking was a javascript not jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you realise you're asking a wrong question, as you're not providing any attempts. However, I'm in a good mood and happened to find this a funny exercise for myself.

Your jQuery (no vanilla javascript) would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lastinput = null;
  $("input").click(function() {
    lastinput = $(this);
  });
  $("option").click(function() {
    if (lastinput != null) {
      lastinput.val($(this).text());
    }
  });
});
```

As shown in this [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwdbxtLu/)

Comment: yes i'm sorry about that, it's just that i really bad with javascript so i don't even know where to start to try..
btw your answer is works exactlly like what i am planning, thank you so much sir :)

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're using jQuery? If not it becomes a little more difficult, but still very possible.

```
// we have a variable to track which textbox we clicked on most recently
var focused = null;
$('input').focus(function(){
    focused = this;
});

// when an option is clicked, we set the recently clicked textbox's value
$('option').click(function(){
    if(focused){
        $(focused).val($(this).text());
    }
});
```

Learn more about jQuery's [Focus](https://api.jquery.com/focus/) and [Click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) functions.

Comment: Your answer doesn't differ from mine, other than that you're using the `focus` (instead of the `click` function I do).

Comment: I didn't see any answers when I posted. Great minds must think alike.